# How can I exclude the first match in a regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following regex, so far:

```
([0-9]+){1}\s*[xX]\s*([A-Za-z\./%\$\s\*]+)
```

to be used on strings such as:

> 2x Soup, 2x Meat Balls, 4x Iced Tea

My intent was to capture the number of times something was ordered, as well as the name of item ordered.

In this regular expression however, the multiplier 'x' gets captured before the title. 
How can I make it so that the x is ignored, and what comes after the x (and a space) is captured?

Comment: C#, although right now I'm just testing with RegExr

Comment: I added a c# solution. In Regexr you can see the content of the capturing groups when you are hovering over the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ignore something in the middle of the pattern. Therefore you do have your capturing groups.

```
([0-9]+){1}\s*[xX]\s*([A-Za-z\./%\$\s\*]+)
^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The marked parts of your pattern are stored in capturing groups, because of the brackets around them.

Your number is in group 1 and the name is in group 2. The "x" is not captured in a group.

How you now access your groups depends on the language you are using.

Btw. the `{1}` is obsolete.

So for c# try this:

```
string text = "2x Soup, 2x Meat Balls, 4x Iced Tea";
MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches(text, @"([0-9]+)\s*[xX]\s*([A-Za-z\./%\$\s\*]+)");

int counter = 0;

foreach (Match m in result)
{
    counter++;
    Console.WriteLine("Order {0}: " + m.Groups[1] + " " + m.Groups[2], counter);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Further I would change the regex to this, since it seems you want to match as name every character till the next comma

```
@"([0-9]+)\s*x\s*([^,]+)"
```

and use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` to avoid having to write [xX]

Comment: the X is captured by the second group.

Comment: With which regex and which input? Can't be with those from my answer. One x is needed between the first and the second group, if there is no x it will not match at all, if there are two x the second will be in the second group.